# Play stop para animación de onda de sonido jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hola quería saber si es posible generar un rutina en jquery para darle play y stop a la animación de la onda de música, si ambos jquery que adjunte como ejemplo se pueden integrar..

```js
var elem = $('.musica');
var count = elem.length;

var loop = function(){ 
  
  setTimeout(function(){
    elem.each(function(){
      var $this = $(this);
      var height = (Math.random() * 30) + 1;
      $this.css({
        'background': 'linear-gradient(to top, rgba(61, 175, 5,'+(.75-($this.index()/count)/2)+'),yellow)',
        'bottom': height,
        'height': height
      });
    });
    
    loop();
  }, 300);
  
}
    
loop();


$('#play').on('click', function(event) {
    console.log('play click clicked');
    $('#pause').show();
    $('#play').hide();
});

$('#pause').on('click', function(event) {
    $('#pause').hide();
    $('#play').show();
});
```

```css
.musica {
 background: #000;
  float: left;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 20px 1px 0 0;
  position: relative;
  transition: all linear 300ms;
  width: 2px;
  -webkit-box-reflect:below -1px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(0.35, transparent), to(white));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="play-stop-mobile hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
    <a href="#" id="play">
       <i class="fa fa-play-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </a> 
   <a href="#" id="pause" style="display: none;">
    <i class="fa fa-stop-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </a>
</div>  
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si se puede, la funcion `setTimeout()` la ingresamos dentro de una variable (`tiempo`) la cual al momento de dar click en pause se quitara el `timeout` con la funcion `clearTimeout()` y al dar play vuelves a ejecutar la funcion.

```js
var elem = $('.musica');
var count = elem.length;
var tiempo;

 var loop = function(){ 
    tiempo = setTimeout(function(){
      elem.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var height = (Math.random() * 30) + 1;
        $this.css({
          'background': 'linear-gradient(to top, rgba(61, 175, 5,'+(.75-($this.index()/count)/2)+'),yellow)',
          'bottom': height,
          'height': height
      });
    });
      loop();  
  }, 300);
}
 loop();



$('#play').on('click', function(event) {
    loop();
    $('#pause').show();
    $('#play').hide();
});

$('#pause').on('click', function(event) {
    clearTimeout(tiempo);
    $('#pause').hide();
    $('#play').show();
});
```

```css
.musica {
 background: #000;
  float: left;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 20px 1px 0 0;
  position: relative;
  transition: all linear 300ms;
  width: 2px;
  -webkit-box-reflect:below -1px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(0.35, transparent), to(white));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="play-stop-mobile hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
    <a href="#" id="play" style="display: none;">
       <i class="fa fa-play-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </a> 
   <a href="#" id="pause">
    <i class="fa fa-stop-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </a>
</div>  
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
```

Comment: Muy bueno Santiago y si quisera que arranque funcionando la onda y luego le doy stop y para? que es lo que tendría que cambiar del script?

Comment: @ElectricMarian Ya edite la respuesta con tus requisitos.

Comment: Sos un genio Santiago! muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Si, mira :

Documentation in english API Jquery:

**When .stop() is called on an element, the currently-running animation (if any) is immediately stopped. If, for instance, an element is being hidden with .slideUp() when .stop() is called, the element will now still be displayed, but will be a fraction of its previous height. Callback functions are not called.**

Pero traduciendotelo es :

Cuando es llamado .stop desde un elemento puedes detener su accion(animacion en este caso)

mira aqui tienes un ejemplo :

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>stop demo</title>
  <style>
  div {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #abc;
    left: 0px;
    top: 30px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    margin: 5px;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<button id="go">Go</button>
<button id="stop">STOP!</button>
<button id="back">Back</button>
<div class="block"></div>
 
<script>
// Start animation
$( "#go" ).click(function() {
  $( ".block" ).animate({ left: "+=100px" }, 2000 );
});
 
// Stop animation when button is clicked
$( "#stop" ).click(function() {
  $( ".block" ).stop();
});
 
// Start animation in the opposite direction
$( "#back" ).click(function() {
  $( ".block" ).animate({ left: "-=100px" }, 2000 );
});
</script>
 
</body>
</html>
```

puedes utilizar la parte esta para a proyecto adaptandola de esta manera :

```
// Stop animation when button is clicked
    $( "#play" ).click(function() {
    console.log('play click clicked');
      $( "#play" ).stop();
    });
```

Comment: gracias Gilberto por la info, voy a probarlo

Comment: Denada para estamos aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una variable a modo de flag con dos valores posibles, true y false. Luego le das el valor true o false desde los botones al hacer clic y en el bucle principal loop, solo mueves el gráfico si la variable es true:

```js
var procesar = true;
var elem = $('.musica');
var count = elem.length;

var loop = function(){ 
  setTimeout(function(){
    if (procesar) {
      elem.each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var height = (Math.random() * 30) + 1;
        $this.css({
          'background': 'linear-gradient(to top, rgba(61, 175, 5,'+(.75-($this.index()/count)/2)+'),yellow)',
          'bottom': height,
          'height': height
        });
      });
      loop();
    }
  }, 300);
}
loop();

$('#play').on('click', function(event) {
    console.log('play click clicked');
    $('#pause').show();
    $('#play').hide();
    procesar = true;
    loop();
});

$('#pause').on('click', function(event) {
    $('#pause').hide();
    $('#play').show();
    procesar = false;
});
```

```css
.musica {
 background: #000;
  float: left;
  height: 1px;
  margin: 20px 1px 0 0;
  position: relative;
  transition: all linear 300ms;
  width: 2px;
  -webkit-box-reflect:below -1px -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(transparent), color-stop(0.35, transparent), to(white));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="play-stop-mobile hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg">
    <a href="#" id="play">
       <i class="fa fa-play-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </a> 
   <a href="#" id="pause" style="display: none;">
    <i class="fa fa-stop-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
   </a>
</div>  
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
<div class="musica"></div>
```